# ssh-agent empty everytime I close my terminal

Tags: linux, github, ssh, ssh-agent

Everytime I need to push something to github I have a **Permission Denied** message.

If I execute this commands on terminal:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -c)
ssh-add -l # Response: The agent has no identities.

ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_desktop
```

So this will works normally..
But if I close the terminal, the problem returns again.

---

I see if I have more than 1 line added in ssh-agent, this is not work in github to..

There`s something that I can do to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I just set the SSH key in .git/config file to my project.

ex:

```
[core]
  sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_custom
`
```